# $(document).on() is not executed iniside a script loaded with $.getScript()

Tags: jquery

Inside a $(document).on() I load an external js file via $.getScript(), the loaded file in turn has a $(document).on() method that is never executed. Why is this happening? 
Im using jquery 1.12.0.

```
<file1.js>
var event = new Event('app_Ready');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
$(document).on("app_Ready", function() {
   alert("app_Ready ok file1");//this works ok
   $.getScript("file2.js");
}

<file2.js>
$(document).on("app_Ready", function() {
   alert("app_Ready ok file2");//this doesnt work
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `file2.js` will only be executed when the `app_Ready` event is triggered after the file has been loaded. Try doing that in `$.getScript`'s callback function.

```
$.getScript("file2.js", function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Or you could just get rid of the `$(document).on()` in `file2.js`, and run the code immediately. It's not clear why it's needed there, since the file isn't loaded until after the event has occurred.